# Default settings on config read fail

Tags: configuration, default, config

I have a method for parsing a config file into a dictionary. I'm unsure how it should behave if a config parameter is missing. Should it use a default value and log an error or raise an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you separate: (1) the parsing of the configuration file and storing the parsed details into a dictionary, from (2) retrieving *name=value* pairs from the dictionary. This separation of concerns will then enable you to provide an overloaded API for (2) that specifies if a missing *name=value* pair should result in a default value being returned or an exception being raised. For example (pseudo code):

```
cfg = parseConfigurationFile("example.cfg")
x = cfg.lookupString("x"); // throws an exception if the name=value is missing
y = cfg.lookupString("y", "hello, World!"); // returns default value if name=value is missing
```

I also suggest that the API should provide type-safe lookup methods such as `lookupInt()`, `lookupBoolean()`, `lookupDouble()` and so on. Those methods should throw an exception if a looked-up value cannot be parsed into the specified type.

**Edit to respond to a comment**

> "Thanks for the example. I was more wondering if it was a good idea to even
>   provide default settings and start the application if the config was wrong."

I like the [*Fail Fast Principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast), so I recommend that if any configuration data is invalid, your application should report an error and stop, rather than try to silently repair the error (perhaps by using a default value instead of a bad configuration value) and continue on.

However, I don't think you should necessarily view *missing* name=value pairs as being an error. Instead, it is valid to use a default value for a missing value. If you take this to an extreme by allowing *all* the configuration name=value pairs to be optional, then your application will be able to work "out of the box" without any configuration file at all, which arguably improves the application's ease of use for new users.

A few years ago, I wrote [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) (C++ and Java libraries for parsing a particular configuration-file syntax). Config4* provides an elegant way to enable any/all name=value pairs to be optional: it's what the Config4* manual calls *fallback configuration*. If you want to learn about that, then I suggest you skim-read Chapter 2 of the *Config4* Getting Started Guide* to get an understanding of the configuration syntax, and then read Chapter 3 of the same manual to understand the API. Pay particular attention to Sections 3.6.2 (*Parsing Embedded Configuration*) and 3.6.3 (*Using Fallback Configuration*).

Comment: Thanks for the example. I was more wondering if it was a good idea to even provide default settings and start the application if the config was wrong.